# yii2: problems using google/apiclient for oAuth and token authentication

Tags: php, google-api, yii2, google-authentication

My project is built on Yii2 and uses `google/apiclient` for the purposes of login to the web interface.  There's also an android app which connects to the API and uses bearer authentication against Google tokens (which I believe pulled in `firebase/jwt`).  This has worked fine since early 2018 until the week commencing 10th September 2018.  No code was changed in my system.

Since then, attempting to login to the web interface (oAuth) gives

> yii\authclient\InvalidResponseException: Request failed with code: 400, message: {
>     "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch",
>     "error_description" : "Bad Request"

The site is correctly listed in the Google developer console (where I've also not changed anything) so the `redirect_uri_mismatch` is not expected.

Upgrading `google/apiclient` allows me to login to the web interface but breaks the app's token auth, giving:

> Your request was made with invalid credentials

I can provide the full stack trace if required, however, I'm hoping someone else has encountered the same and can point me in the right direction.  Using `firebase/jwt` v4 in the live system allows token auth to function but using v4 in test with the upgraded `google/apiclient` fails the auth with the same credentials error as above.

Can anyone provide any guidance please?

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/issues/206#issuecomment-423293728

Comment: That describes a similar problem, and upgrading solves the problem signing in to the web interface with oAuth, but unfortunately doing that breaks token authentication (same issue as original post).

Answer (score 0):

To get refresh token on first login you need to set "?access_type=offline" in "authUrl". And then save it somewhere, in database, files etc.

If you have no database or if you ok with prompting access rights every time on login in you can add "&approval_prompt=force" to same URL. Thats will enforce Google send you refresh token every time you are logging in, but also enforces showing access rights prompt every time.

```
class MyGoogleClient extends yii\authclient\clients\Google
{

        /**
         * Set to true if you want to get refresh token always on login
         * @var type
         */
        public $enforceRefreshToken = false;

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function init()
        {
            parent::init();

            if (is_array($this->scope)) {
                $this->scope = implode(' ', $this->scope);
            }

            $additionalParams = [];
            if ($this->autoRefreshAccessToken) {
                $additionalParams['access_type'] = 'offline';
            }
            if ($this->enforceRefreshToken) {
                $additionalParams['approval_prompt'] = 'force';
            }
            if (!empty($additionalParams)) {
                $this->authUrl = $this->composeUrl($this->authUrl, $additionalParams);
            }
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         * @return string return URL.
         */
        protected function defaultReturnUrl()
        {
            return Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createAbsoluteUrl([Yii::$app->controller->getRoute(), 'authclient' => 'google']);
        }

    }
```